# How to use GetWebRequest method in .NetCore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, httpwebrequest

below is the code from .NET FRAMEWORK 4.8. I am porting code to .NET Core.How can I convert this to .NET Core ?

```
{

  public partial class Service : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol
  {
    protected override System.Net.WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
    {
      System.Net.HttpWebRequest webRequest = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(uri);
      webRequest.KeepAlive = false;
      return webRequest;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There's no SoapHttpClientProtocol in .NET Core. What are you trying to do? If you want to make an HTTP GET call, use HttpClient. If you want to call a SOAP service create a proxy through the [Add > Connected Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide) dialog

Comment: More to the point, there's no `System.Web` in .NET Core. Anything in that whole namespace is off-limits.